# как сделать так, чтобы id прибавлялся на 1 при каждой записи в таблицу?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

есть таблица:

```
--------------------
|   id   | username|
--------------------
|   1    |  nick   |
|   2    |  nick3  |
|   3    |  nick2  |
-------------------
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом добавлении пользователя в таблицу id прибавлялся на единицу? (не в коде, а при самом создании таблицы)

Comment: Поле `id` следует определить как автоинкрементное. Но учтите - значения имеют полное право  быть не непрерывными. Альтернативный вариант - программная генерация, но она неустойчива к параллельным запросам (может порождать дубликаты).

Comment: да, но как поставить автоинкрементное число в sqlite?

Comment: [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 4):

При создании таблицы на примере `sqlite` создайте таблицу, далее добавьте новый столбец. Поставьте галочку напротив `Первичный ключ`,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее настроить `Первичный ключ`. Далее поставьте галку напротив `Автоинкремент`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее `Применить` и `окей`

Потом, если надо создайте еще столбцы и под конец нажмите галочку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего у вас создастся таблица, у которой `id` будет автоматически увеличиваться на 1.

P.S. В виде кода

`id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` - это создание автоинкрементного поля через код, взято [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) - тут соответственно ваше поле id, а не как в примере `Personid`

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);
```

Comment: через код нужно

Comment: @ЕгорКолесников Дополнил ответ с тем, как это сделать через код. Плюс при создании таблицы через `SQLiteStudio`, когда нажали на галочку перед вами будет выведен код.